# Looping reversed video in HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have an embedded video which plays in a loop on mouse hover and pauses on mouse out. I would eventually like to have it so that the video loops in the normal direction when hovered over on the right hand side, pauses on mouse out, and loops in the reverse direction when hovered over on the left hand side.

Here is my current code:

```
<video id="360-rotation" src="Earth Rotation.mp4" width="640" height="640" loop></video>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverVideo);
var video = document.getElementById('360-rotation');

function hoverVideo(event) {
    if (event.target == video) {
        video.play();
        this.addEventListener('mouseout', stopHoverVideo);
    }
}

function stopHoverVideo(event) {
    if (event.target == video) {
        video.pause();
        //video.playbackRate = -1;
    }
}
```

I have done some research and it seems that loop doesn't support negative values of playbackRate. Is there any other way of achieving this?